# How to Dynamically set the index of array in the name attribute of the input field using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to Dynamically set the index of array in the name attribute of the input field using javascript?

```
<input type="text" name="item[][name]">
<input type="text" name="item[][description]">
<input type="text" name="item[][brand]">
```

If I add thesame set of input fields or duplicate it using javascript  the result should be like below:

```
<input type="text" name="item[0][name]">
<input type="text" name="item[0][description]">
<input type="text" name="item[0][brand]">

<input type="text" name="item[1][name]">
<input type="text" name="item[1][description]">
<input type="text" name="item[1][brand]">
```

Comment: How are you generating these HTML code ? Using JavaScript or ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing ? Are you trying to write a "loop" to build many inputs group ? Are you directly writing the html or using templates ?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu yes I used the javascript clone to duplicate the set of input fields.

Comment: @FerdinandBalbin Using like `item[][name]` will not fetch the value from `item[][name]` and assign it to input name field. Rather your input filed name will be set to `item[][name]`. Are you trying to loop the array and assign it's values as name of input field ?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu no I did not use a loop there only javascript clone. If I click a button it will add thesame set of fields and thesame name attributes. What I'd like to do is as I click the add button thesame set of fields but different name index of array. item[0][name] ->  item[1][name]

Comment: @FerdinandBalbin If you let me know what exactly you are trying to achieve, i can help in a better way :)

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Actually I have setup a registration form for item data and I wanted to save multiple Item at one click. To do this I created a form where I can dynamically add another set of fields so that I can save multiple items.  And in order to add another set of fields I used the javascript clone to duplicate thesame set of fields where I can enter item data and to collect those data in the form I used 'form.serialize()' and submit it using ajax. The problem is in the multiple insert part because it only place the serialized data in one array even though it has a two set.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you do a wrong thing.
If you create this fields with js put index there.

Example with plain js.

```
var maxInputNum = 5;

var inputName = document.createElement('input'),
    inputDescription = document.createElement('input'),
    inputBrand = document.createElement('input');

maxInputNum++;
inputName.name = 'item[' + maxInputNum + '][name]';
inputDescription.name = 'item[' + maxInputNum + '][description]';
inputBrand.name = 'item[' + maxInputNum + '][brand]';

form.appendChild(inputName);
form.appendChild(inputDescription);
form.appendChild(inputBrand);
```

Of course you could use jQuery to simplify example.

```
var maxInputNum = 5;

maxInputNum++;
var $inputName = $('<input type="text" name="item[' + maxInputNum + '][name]">'),
    $inputDescription = $('<input type="text" name="item[' + maxInputNum + '][brand]">'),
    $inputBrand = $('<input type="text" name="item[' + maxInputNum + '][description]">');

$('#form').append($inputName);
$('#form').append($inputDescription);
$('#form').append($inputBrand);
```

**But better solution is using something like angularjs.**

Answer (score 1):

Here you can update all name attribute that container "[digits]" with its order in the selected array of HTMLElements.  you can create a function called update order and call it every time something happened and affect order ... Sort Order in Sortable Elements or Delete Element of the array.

```
       $("input").each(function (indexitem, itemdata) {
            var name = $(itemdata).attr("name");
            if (name !== undefined && name !== null) {
                const regex = /\[[\d]+\]/gi;
                var newname = name.replace(regex, `[${index}]`);
                $(itemdata).attr("name", newname);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simple remove index numbers instead of sequencing. Browsers still will pass the values as an array while keeping order.

```
let allIndexedElements=document.querySelectorAll('[name*="item[]"');
for (const el of allIndexedElements) {
    el.name = el.name.replace(/\[\d+\]/ig, '[]');
 }
```

If you want to make sure the order will be kept, you can increment an index number instead of removing it.